# Calculations from table data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate some counts and average timespans from the data in table:

```css
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| STATS_I | TASK_I | TYPE | CREATE_TS | END_TS   |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 1       | 111    | A    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 2       | 111    | A    | 30-05-16  |          |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 3       | 111    | B    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 4       | 111    | B    | 30-05-16  |          |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 5       | 111    | C    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 6       | 222    | D    | 30-05-16  |          |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 7       | 222    | D    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 8       | 222    | C    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 9       | 222    | C    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 10      | 222    | C    | 30-05-16  |          |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 11      | 333    | A    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 12      | 333    | B    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 13      | 333    | B    | 30-05-16  | 31-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 14      | 333    | D    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 15      | 333    | D    | 30-05-16  | 31-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 16      | 444    | D    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 17      | 444    | D    | 30-05-16  | 31-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 18      | 444    | C    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 19      | 444    | B    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 20      | 444    | A    | 30-05-16  | 30-05-16 |
+---------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
```

The sample table can be populated with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "STATS" ("STATS_I" NUMBER(10,0), "TASK_I" NUMBER(10,0), "TYPE" VARCHAR2(30), "CREATE_TS" DATE, "END_TS" DATE); 
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (1,111,'A',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (2,111,'A',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),null);
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (3,111,'B',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (4,111,'B',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),null);
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (5,111,'C',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (6,222,'D',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),null);
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (7,222,'D',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (8,222,'C',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (9,222,'C',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (10,222,'C',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),null);
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (11,333,'A',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (12,333,'B',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (13,333,'B',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),null);
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (14,333,'D',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (15,333,'D',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),null);
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (16,444,'D',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (17,444,'D',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),null);
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (18,444,'C',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (19,444,'B',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into STATS (STATS_I,TASK_I,TYPE,CREATE_TS,END_TS) values (20,444,'A',to_date('30-05-16','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('31-05-16','DD-MM-RR'));
```

-  `end_ts` and `create_ts` are kept at 10 minutes difference

The output I'm trying to get is:

```html
+--------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| Task_i | A            | B                 | C                 | D     |
+        +--------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|        | Count | Read | Count | Avg. Time | Count | Avg. Time | Count |
|        |       |      |       |   to Read |       |   to Read |       |
+--------+-------+------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
| 111    | 2     | 1    | 2     | 10 min    | 1     | 10 min    | 0     |
+--------+-------+------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
| 222    | 0     | 0    | 0     | 0 min     | 3     | 10 min    | 2     |
+--------+-------+------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
| 333    | 1     | 1    | 2     | 10 min    | 0     | 0 min     | 2     |
+--------+-------+------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
| 444    | 1     | 1    | 1     | 10 min    | 1     | 10 min    | 2     |
+--------+-------+------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
```

Where for each `task_i`:

- 'Count' is the count of rows for the type;
- 'Read' is the count of rows for the type where `end_ts` is not null
- 'Average time to read' is calculated by `(end_ts - create_ts )/count of type` ignoring the rows where `end_ts` is null

So far I have tried to create four tables, one for each for each type, and then join them on `task_i`:

```
(((select count(*) as A from stats s   where s.type='A' group by s.TYPE  UNION ALL
select count(*) as B from stats s   where s.type='B' group by s.TYPE ) UNION ALL
select count(*) as C from stats s   where s.type='C' group by s.TYPE ) UNION ALL
select count(*) as D from stats s   where s.type='D' group by s.TYPE ) ;
```

but this doesn't produce anything like what I need:

```
         A
----------
         4
         5
         4
         7
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I generate the required output?

Comment: What's your question, and where's your code attempt to solve your question?

Comment: What kind of statistics? Do you have some kind of code to do that? Do you really have a question?
In order to provide help you need to tell us what is your problem, what kind of solutions you tried so far and your particular doubts

Comment: And what is "read" on output?

Comment: please click on result table link for statistic , i am very poor in sql ,so didn't share my poor try

Comment: Regardless of your SQL abilities, please show us your attempt, and tell us all issues that you're having with this attempt, so you can improve this question from it's current state, little more than a beg for code, into a true question. Your lack of attempt is one reason for the down-votes, votes that can prevent you from asking future questions if the recur.

Comment: i tried this way (((select count(*) as A from stats s   where s.type='A' group by s.TYPE  UNION ALL
select count(*) as B from stats s   where s.type='B' group by s.TYPE ) UNION ALL
select count(*) as C from stats s   where s.type='C' group by s.TYPE ) UNION ALL
select count(*) as D from stats s   where s.type='D' group by s.TYPE ) ;

Comment: I need these in one row but all falls one after another

Comment: Please edit your question, show your code and your issues. This information is too important to bury in comments.

Comment: The counts are straightforward, but you still haven't said what `read` is - the number of matches where `end_ts` isn't null perhaps? And where does the average read time come from, the difference between `create_ts` and `end_ts` where that is set? (How do they have 5 minutes - you're creating all your dates at midnight?) Also please show your expected results as formatted text, not an image.

Comment: @AlexPoole ,  i have made some edit please see

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels made some edits please see

Comment: @Kronos please see edit made

Comment: The dates you are inserting in the sample table are all at midnight (since you don't specify a different time); so why are the averages 24 hours and 5 minutes - where does that come from? Maybe you can adjust your data to show the full time. (If you're querying your real table to get that, use `to_char(end_ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` etc.) I'm also not sure how your averages relate to the data you've shown - are the last two rows for the C data switched, for example?

Comment: @AlexPoole apologies  only time column is having incorrect dummy data,  , end_ts and start_ts is in dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss

Comment: Average time is calculated by (total  (end_ts - create_ts )) of type say'B'/ total count of type say'B' for each task_i say'111' except those where end_ts is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counts, which are the part you attempted, can be found with a conditional count - with a case expression inside - rather than with a union:

```
select task_i,
  count(case when type = 'A' then 1 end) as a_count,
  count(case when type = 'B' then 1 end) as b_count,
  count(case when type = 'C' then 1 end) as c_count,
  count(case when type = 'D' then 1 end) as d_count
from stats
group by task_i
order by task_i;

    TASK_I    A_COUNT    B_COUNT    C_COUNT    D_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       111          2          2          1          0
       222          0          0          2          3
       333          1          2          0          2
       444          1          1          1          2
```

The number of 'reads', where `end_ts is not null`, can be found by modifying the case expression:

```
select task_i,
  count(case when type = 'A' then 1 end) as a_count,
  count(case when type = 'A' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as a_read,
  count(case when type = 'B' then 1 end) as b_count,
  count(case when type = 'B' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as b_read,
  count(case when type = 'C' then 1 end) as c_count,
  count(case when type = 'C' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as c_read,
  count(case when type = 'D' then 1 end) as d_count
from stats
group by task_i
order by task_i;

    TASK_I    A_COUNT     A_READ    B_COUNT     B_READ    C_COUNT     C_READ    D_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       111          2          1          2          1          1          1          0
       222          0          0          0          0          2          1          3
       333          1          1          2          1          0          0          2
       444          1          1          1          1          1          1          2
```

The elapse time can be found the same way really, but using `avg()` instead of `count()`:

```
select task_i,
  count(case when type = 'A' then 1 end) as a_count,
  count(case when type = 'A' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as a_read,
  avg(case when type = 'A' and end_ts is not null then end_ts - create_ts end) as a_readtime,
  count(case when type = 'B' then 1 end) as b_count,
  count(case when type = 'B' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as b_read,
  avg(case when type = 'B' and end_ts is not null then end_ts - create_ts end) as b_readtime,
  count(case when type = 'C' then 1 end) as c_count,
  count(case when type = 'C' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as c_read,
  avg(case when type = 'C' and end_ts is not null then end_ts - create_ts end) as c_readtime,
  count(case when type = 'D' then 1 end) as d_count
from stats
group by task_i
order by task_i;

    TASK_I    A_COUNT     A_READ A_READTIME    B_COUNT     B_READ B_READTIME    C_COUNT     C_READ C_READTIME    D_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       111          2          1     1.0035          2          1     1.0035          1          1     1.0035          0
       222          0          0                     0          0                     2          1     1.0035          3
       333          1          1     1.0035          2          1     1.0035          0          0                     2
       444          1          1     1.0035          1          1     1.0035          1          1     1.0035          2
```

The date arithmetic means those are shown in fractions of a day; I've amended your data slightly to add five minutes to each end time, to closer match your original results. To get the string output you need you have to manipulate those a bit, and that's a bit less repetitive if you use an inline view to do the calculation:

```
select task_i,
  a_count,
  a_read,
  case when a_readtime > 1 then trunc(24 * a_readtime) || ' hrs ' end
    || round(60 * mod(24 * nvl(a_readtime, 0), 1)) || ' min'
    as a_readtime
from (
  select task_i,
    count(case when type = 'A' then 1 end) as a_count,
    count(case when type = 'A' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as a_read,
    avg(case when type = 'A' and end_ts is not null then end_ts - create_ts end) as a_readtime,
    count(case when type = 'B' then 1 end) as b_count,
    count(case when type = 'B' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as b_read,
    avg(case when type = 'B' and end_ts is not null then end_ts - create_ts end) as b_readtime,
    count(case when type = 'C' then 1 end) as c_count,
    count(case when type = 'C' and end_ts is not null then 1 end) as c_read,
    avg(case when type = 'C' and end_ts is not null then end_ts - create_ts end) as c_readtime,
    count(case when type = 'D' then 1 end) as d_count
  from stats
  group by task_i
)
order by task_i;

    TASK_I    A_COUNT     A_READ A_READTIME    
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
       111          2          1 24 hrs 5 min   
       222          0          0 0 min            
       333          1          1 24 hrs 5 min   
       444          1          1 24 hrs 5 min
```

... and repeat the outer query select list items for the same data for B, C and D.

If you're on 11g or higher you could use `pivot` to avoid repeating the translation of the time difference into a string:

```
select * from (
  select task_i, type, type_count, type_read,
    case when type_readtime > 1 then trunc(24 * type_readtime) || ' hrs ' end
      || round(60 * mod(24 * type_readtime, 1)) || ' min'
    as type_readtime
  from (
    select task_i,
      type,
      count(*) as type_count,
      count(case when end_ts is not null then 1 end) as type_read,
      avg(case when end_ts is not null then end_ts - create_ts end) as type_readtime
    from stats
    group by task_i, type
  )
)
pivot (max(type_count) as count, max(type_read) as read, max(type_readtime) as readtime
  for (type) in ('A' as a, 'B' as b, 'C' as c, 'D' as d))
order by task_i;

    TASK_I    A_COUNT     A_READ A_READTIME         B_COUNT     B_READ B_READTIME         C_COUNT     C_READ C_READTIME         D_COUNT     D_READ D_READTIME    
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
       111          2          1 24 hrs 5 min             2          1 24 hrs 5 min             1          1 24 hrs 5 min                                         
       222                                                                                      2          1 24 hrs 5 min             3          2 24 hrs 5 min   
       333          1          1 24 hrs 5 min             2          1 24 hrs 5 min                                                   2          1 24 hrs 5 min   
       444          1          1 24 hrs 5 min             1          1 24 hrs 5 min             1          1 24 hrs 5 min             2          1 24 hrs 5 min
```

... but if you don't want null values you'll need to replace them with `nvl()` calls in the final select list, which makes it messier again.

Comment: many  thanks for this ,  though  i am getting count results  accurately but  time calculation i am still analysing  and i see some discrepancy

Comment: Are you sure all your actual data is at midnight? Did you look at the raw data with a format model that shows the time?

Comment: let me explain this way : let consider type 'C'  where end_ts and create_ts is having difference of 1 minute  for all task_i  so result should be 1 minute for all task_i except for task_i =333

Comment: @djCode - it would be much easier if you made the data in the question (including the inserts) more realistic - showing the times for a start. And when you say a difference of one minute, do you mean *exactly* that, or are some 45 seconds, some 50, some 72 etc.? The average is rounding as you aren't showing seconds, which might be confusing you.

Comment: Apologies again for same ,  give me some time i will update the same

Comment: many thanks for putting the question correctly,  i have updated the same  for input vs output

Comment: issue with query is that  readtime should be divided by read count

Comment: The average isn't doing that? I don't understand what you mean. Why would you divide the average by the count? If the gap between all the create and end times is 10 minutes (which you still aren't showing in the imserts) then the average of those is also 10 minutes.

Comment: we are considering here only those entries with end_ts in not null

Comment: i explain with task_i = '222' and type 'C', here we have total count 3 and read count 2 (where end_ts in not null)  so avg tvg  time = 3(10 min)/3*2 and we get 5 min which is correct

Comment: If that's the calculation you really want that's fine - you can adapt this however you need - but it isn't what you said in the question, and I don't see how you can call it an average. And why is it 3x10 if only two have an end time? Why isn't it 10+10 (sum of length of both periods with end times) divided by 2 (number wiith end times)?

Comment: yes you are correct then the average of those is also 10 minutes. my mistake

Comment: we need time difference only in minutes and not in hrs and min

Comment: @djCode - so more than a day would be shown as thousands of minutes? You can just change the `type_readtime` expression to `round(1440 * type_readtime) || ' min'`.